# std::array with aggregate initialization on g++ generates huge code

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, stdarray, loop-unrolling

On g++ 4.9.2 and 5.3.1, this code takes several seconds to compile and produces a 52,776 byte executable:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = 4096;

    struct S
    {
        float f;
        S() : f(0.0f) {}
    };

    std::array<S, size> a = {};  // <-- note aggregate initialization

    for (auto& e : a)
        std::cerr << e.f;

    return 0;
}
```

Increasing `size` seems to increase compilation time and executable size linearly. I cannot reproduce this behaviour with either clang 3.5 or Visual C++ 2015. Using `-Os` makes no difference.

```
$ time g++ -O2 -std=c++11 test.cpp
real    0m4.178s
user    0m4.060s
sys     0m0.068s
```

Inspecting the assembly code reveals that the initialization of `a` is unrolled, generating *4096* `movl` instructions:

```
main:
.LFB1313:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    subq    $16384, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16400
    movl    $0x00000000, (%rsp)
    movl    $0x00000000, 4(%rsp)
    movq    %rsp, %rbx
    movl    $0x00000000, 8(%rsp)
    movl    $0x00000000, 12(%rsp)
    movl    $0x00000000, 16(%rsp)
       [...skipping 4000 lines...]
    movl    $0x00000000, 16376(%rsp)
    movl    $0x00000000, 16380(%rsp)
```

This only happens when `T` has a non-trivial constructor and the array is initialized using `{}`. If I do any of the following, g++ generates a simple loop:

1. Remove `S::S()`;
2. Remove `S::S()` and initialize `S::f` in-class;
3. Remove the aggregate initialization (`= {}`);
4. Compile without `-O2`.

I'm all for loop unrolling as an optimization, but I don't think this is a very good one. Before I report this as a bug, can someone confirm whether this is the expected behaviour?

[edit: I've opened [a new bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71165) for this because the others don't seem to match. They were more about long compilation time than weird codegen.]

Comment: Wow.  g++ does this in 6.1 as well.  I got the compiler to crash and issue a submit bug warning on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/Ae75GH

Comment: @NathanOliver Welp, that kinda confirms it. Thanks.

Comment: gcc's handling of constexpr array is also suspect. It does a similar thing when initialising a constexpr std::array<char, N> = make_array(...) where make_array() is constexpr.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, I think gcc gets killed because it's taking [too many resources](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/gcc-explorer/blob/master/c-preload/compiler-wrapper). I couldn't reproduce a crash anywhere else.

Comment: @isanae Oops.  I think my comment was all together accurate.  I just wanted to show you that it was also broken in 6.1.  The fact that it said to file a bug report was just a happy coincidence.

Comment: Fixed on GCC 12 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92385#c13

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There appears to be a related bug report, [Bug 59659 - large zero-initialized std::array compile time excessive](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659). It was considered "fixed" for 4.9.0, so I consider this testcase either a regression or an edgecase not covered by the patch. For what it's worth, two of the bug report's test cases<sup>[1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659#c6), [2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659#c2)</sup> exhibit symptoms for me on both GCC 4.9.0 as well as 5.3.1

There are two more related bug reports:

[Bug 68203 - Аbout infinite compilation time on struct with nested array of pairs with -std=c++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68203)

> Andrew Pinski 2015-11-04 07:56:57 UTC
>
> This is most likely a memory hog which is generating lots of default
>   constructors rather than a loop over them.

That one claims to be a duplicate of this one:

[Bug 56671 - Gcc uses large amounts of memory and processor power with large C++11 bitsets](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56671)

> Jonathan Wakely 2016-01-26 15:12:27 UTC
>
> Generating the array initialization for this constexpr constructor is
>   the problem:
>
> ```
>   constexpr _Base_bitset(unsigned long long __val) noexcept
>   : _M_w{ _WordT(__val)
>    } { }
> ```

Indeed if we change it to `S a[4096] {};` we don't get the problem.

---

Using `perf` we can see where GCC is spending most of its time. First:

`perf record g++ -std=c++11 -O2 test.cpp`

Then `perf report`:

```
  10.33%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] get_ref_base_and_extent
   6.36%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] memrefs_conflict_p
   6.25%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] vn_reference_lookup_2
   6.16%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] exp_equiv_p
   5.99%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] walk_non_aliased_vuses
   5.02%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] find_base_term
   4.98%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] invalidate
   4.73%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] write_dependence_p
   4.68%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] estimate_calls_size_and_time
   4.11%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] ix86_find_base_term
   3.41%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] rtx_equal_p
   2.87%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] cse_insn
   2.77%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] record_store
   2.66%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] vn_reference_eq
   2.48%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] operand_equal_p
   1.21%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] integer_zerop
   1.00%  cc1plus   cc1plus                 [.] base_alias_check
```

This won't mean much to anyone but GCC developers but it's still interesting to see what's taking up so much compilation time.

---

Clang 3.7.0 does a much better job at this than GCC. At `-O2` it takes less than a second to compile, produces a much smaller executable (8960 bytes) and this assembly:

```
0000000000400810 <main>:
  400810:   53                      push   rbx
  400811:   48 81 ec 00 40 00 00    sub    rsp,0x4000
  400818:   48 8d 3c 24             lea    rdi,[rsp]
  40081c:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
  40081e:   31 f6                   xor    esi,esi
  400820:   ba 00 40 00 00          mov    edx,0x4000
  400825:   e8 56 fe ff ff          call   400680 <memset@plt>
  40082a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  400830:   f3 0f 10 04 1c          movss  xmm0,DWORD PTR [rsp+rbx*1]
  400835:   f3 0f 5a c0             cvtss2sd xmm0,xmm0
  400839:   bf 60 10 60 00          mov    edi,0x601060
  40083e:   e8 9d fe ff ff          call   4006e0 <_ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_@plt>
  400843:   48 83 c3 04             add    rbx,0x4
  400847:   48 81 fb 00 40 00 00    cmp    rbx,0x4000
  40084e:   75 e0                   jne    400830 <main+0x20>
  400850:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  400852:   48 81 c4 00 40 00 00    add    rsp,0x4000
  400859:   5b                      pop    rbx
  40085a:   c3                      ret    
  40085b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

On the other hand with GCC 5.3.1, with no optimizations, it compiles very quickly but still produces a 95328 sized executable. Compiling with `-O2` reduces the executable size to 53912 but compilation time takes 4 seconds. I would *definitely* report this to their bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks. clang isn't that smart though. If I initialize `f` to something else than 0, it will do *both* a `memset` and a loop. But it won't unroll anything.

Comment: In fact, a test case in [one of the comments](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659#c6) for this bug report is still failing with similar symptoms.

Comment: @isanae [This one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659#c2) as well. I don't think the issue was "fixed" at all, considering that they exhibit symptoms on 4.9.x. So it's probably not a regression but an invalid-fix.

Comment: @isanae Anyways I went into the rabbit hole and just came back up with more bug reports. I'd consider it "unresolved" and use one of the various workarounds.

Comment: I appreciate the dig. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your GCC bug [71165](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71165), then merged with [92385](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92385), has been fixed on GCC 12.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eGMq16esP