# Extreme memory usage with large arrays of an Object

Tags: c++, object, compilation, ram, large-data

Why is it that when compiling `Sample 1`, it uses all my RAM and crashes my computer yet `Sample 2` compiles instantly without doing so?

Sample 1:

```
class Foo
{
    int a = 0;
};

class Test
{
    Foo foo[4000000] = {};
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
}
```

Sample 2:

```
class Foo
{
    int a = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo[4000000] = {};
}
```

Lastly, is there any way to stop Sample 1 from using tons of RAM when compiling? I'm using `gcc version 5.3.0` and I compiled the above with `-std=c++11`. Note that `class Test` should only require a mere 16 MB of memory.

For any

Comment: `it uses all my RAM and crashes my computer` If GCC does that, it's obviously a compiler bug.

Comment: Fascinating. I'm going to guess that gcc is attempting to create a constructor for the object by generating the code to initialize each one of the four million instances of `Foo` in `Test`'s class. Dunno why gcc can't do it the same way as it does in the second example. P.S. `class Test` should require 16mb of memory, 4 million * 4 bytes per int.

Comment: It's not terribly unreasonable to generate unoptimized code and then optimize it. Though, obviously, that yields dramatically suboptimal results in this case.

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely a bug. I can reproduce this with 5.3 on my system. RAM usage rapidly increases, but I closed the program because I don't want my system to crash. On the other hand, if I compile it in Clang 3.8, it compiles almost instantly.

I suggest reporting this to gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla. As [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260396/296509) take a look at bug reports 59659, 68203, and 56671. I'm pretty sure they all point to the same problem of GCC's inability to have a large array of non-trivial class type.

Comment: "This is definitely a bug". Proof?

Comment: Also you basically copied the answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260097/stdarray-with-aggregate-initialization-on-g-generates-huge-code) question. Please give credit where credit is due.