# Trying to understand cause of increased compile time going from C++11 to C++14

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, g++, c++14

Migrating from C++11 to C++14, I have a source file that usually compiles in ~20s in C++11 mode, but when compiling the same file in C++14 mode the compile time increase to ~340s.  That's an increase of about 17 times.  The size of the generated object code doubles.

So the clarify my question, I'm trying to understand both what in the code and why the compilers takes that much longer for the same code by changing the `-std=c++11/c++14` flag for `g++`.

To make a fair comparison ran the pre-processor over the code (in C++11 mode) and compiled the output with both the C++11 and C++14 flags. E.g.,

```
g++ -E -std=c++11 -g -O2 -o spaghetti.E spaghetti.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++11 -g -O2 -o spaghetti-11.o -x c++ spaghetti.E
g++ -c -std=c++14 -g -O2 -o spaghetti-14.o -x c++ spaghetti.E
```

The file in question does have lots of fixed size arrays of objects in template form like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Object {
    std::array<T,N> storage{};
    std::vector<T> counters;
};
```

Symbols involving `Object` do double when compiled with C++14 over C++11 (among others).

So, what motivates the compiler to take 17 times longer to compile the same file?
And what should change to reduce this?

I should note that if I change the `Object` implementation

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Object {
    std::vector<T> storage{};  // was std::array above, N used in other members
    std::vector<T> counters;
};
```

It will compile quickly under both C++11 and C++14.

Comment: Probably worth posting this as a bug report to the gcc... mailing list? I have no idea how to get in contact with those people.

Comment: You could also compile gcc in debug mode and step through your compilation ;)

Comment: I wonder if this may be due to aggregate initialization of the `storage` array: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37260097/260313

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the GCC version in question.

Comment: @rustyx, file too big and proprietary for quick reduction. Tried both g++ 11.3.0 and 12.0.0 20211212 (experimental) with the same similar hit to compile time.

Comment: I always knew that `spaghetti` code could be hard to modernize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this is [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92385) in `gcc` but isn't getting much traction.
Did you try to switch over to `clang++`?

PS from comment: Removing the `{}` behind the `storage{}` and manually initializing works.

Comment: @oilver, yes, tried with clang++ (v12.0.1) and did not see this problem here.

Comment: Maybe you can initialize it in a proper constructor and remove the `{}` behind the `storage{}`. This at least fixed the related issue for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260097/stdarray-with-aggregate-initialization-on-g-generates-huge-code

Comment: Thank you, yes, compile time problem was gone when removing the `{}` after `storage`.